# SSIS Automation of Export to Excel process

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel, webclient

[image]Wondering if someone can help with a query please. I developed an ssis package to download an Excel file fro Web-Portal using Webclient(). Now i have to do the same for couple more portals. my query is, I am unable to get a download string from "Export To Excel" icon. Is there a c# or VB library in SSIS that can automate "Export to Excel" process for me ?
Many thanks in Advance

Comment: what "download string" are you trying to get?   What steps are you hoping to automate?

Comment: @TabAlleman Manythanks for your reply mate. I am trying to scrape a webportal and trying to automate the process of downloading the data. But website only has "Export to Excel" button. When i hover over the button/ or right click on it. I don't get any download string/url. So can't use Webclient(). I can only manually download the file and view it. I have attached the screenshot to my main/above question